# "Retrieved value" field in custom screen

Tags: customization, infor-eam

I am trying to create a custom screen in Infor EAM 11.4, and add a "retrieved value" field to the screen. This consisted in:

1. Adding an an alpha field F1 to the custom screen, basic, can be null.
2. Creating a query Q1 for retrieving a single-row, single-column table from the value of F1.
3. Adding another alpha field F2 to the custom screen with : Retrieved value checked, Source field = F1, Retrieved value query = Q1.

The only thing I am missing is HOW exactly does EAM pass the value of F1 to Q1 where retrieving the value of F2, if it even does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Functional Brief "Infor EAM User Defined Screens", the arguments in this case are passed in parameters named after the sequence number of the defined fields.

Example:

- The value of the field with sequence number `1` will be passed in bind parameter `:1`
- The value of the field with sequence number `7` will be passed in bind parameter `:7`